# Como llamar desde un Service Callout a un business asincronico proyecto service bus Oracle

Tags: oracle, webservice, asincronismo, osb

Estoy creando un servicio, en el cual necesito colocar un **Service Callout** en mi **Pipeline**, pues debo llamar un **BusinessService** donde su wsdl tiene una estructura de servicio asincrónico, luego de esta llamada, según la respuesta que me devuelva, debo desencadenar otra búsqueda en otro **BusinessService**.

El problema esta cuando intento llamar a este **BusinessService**, y me indica que la estructura que le entrega el wsdl no tiene request y response. Esto es algo obvio, pues el hecho que sea asincronico, su estructura esta separado por dos puertos. Un puerto de entrada, y un puerto de salida, y no en un solo puerto el request y el response.

La pregunta es **¿Como puedo hacer una regla de negocio en mi pipeline llamando servicios asincronicos?**

Llamada desde **Service Callout** a **BusinessService**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**BusinessService**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**WSDL**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que tu necesitas es utilizar un **Publish** y no un **Callout**:

Algunas características del Publish:

- Puede ser sincrónico o asíncrono
- Si llama a un Bussines Service configurado con Calidad de Servicio: Mejor Esfuerzo, entonces será una llamada *asíncrona*.
- Si llama a un Bussines Service configurado con Calidad de servicio: exactamente una vez o al menos una vez, OSB esperará hasta que se complete el procesamiento en el Bussines Service antes de continuar y en realidad se trata de una llamada *síncrona*.
- Si está llamando a un servicio de proxy local, OSB esperará hasta que finalice el procesamiento en el servicio de proxy local y efectivamente se trata de una llamada *síncrona*.
- Puede invocarse desde Pipelines de solicitud y/o respuesta.
- Ideal usarlo cuando no es necesario esperar una respuesta del proceso al que llama.